# react-router: how to navigate from basename to parent route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a parent route `/` as well as  nested child route `/settings` . When I am `/settings` context, I am unable to redirect to parent `/login`. The redirect goes to `/settings/login`. I have presented by parent and child route here. Is any change required ?

Parent block below :

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/' > 
    <React.Fragment>
      < Content />  /* /settings route configured here */
    </React.Fragment>
</BrowserRouter>

class Router extends Component {
render() {
  return (  
    <Switch>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Page} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        </React.Fragment>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

}

Nested block below :

```
 <BrowserRouter basename='/settings'>
          <Router/>
 </BrowserRouter>

class Router extends Component {
render() {
  return (
        <Switch>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path='/' component={User} />
            <Route path='/password' component={ResetPassword} />
          </React.Fragment>
        </Switch>
  );
}
```

}

Comment: can you try to wrap your nested component with **withRouter** from `react-router-dom`. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

Comment: I can access this.props.history in the nested component that passed from top node. Do you want me to explicitly wrap each component ? does it make difference ?

Comment: @kulls try passing `component={() => { window.location.replace('/login'); return null; }}`